# How do I push/pull from Github over openconnect vpn with github ssh auth?

Tags: github, ssh, openconnect

I'm using [openconnect](http://www.infradead.org/openconnect/) in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to ssh into a remote machine over a vpn.  I'm trying to push and pull to/from Github with ssh authentication, but it's not working.  When I try to pull or push, it gives the error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When I connect with [nomachine](https://www.nomachine.com/), I'm able to push/pull with Github no problem.

I've tried googling many different things, and haven't noticed anything yet in the options for openconnect or ssh that would help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was simple:  just set the git url to use the https version instead of ssh.  You can also then cache the username/pass for https for a while: https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/